# ListBox selections does not show up after autopostback

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, autopostback

I know that this is not the first time a question about this issue has been posted here, but I haven't managed to find an answer to my question.

I have a number of ListBoxes on my page:

```
<tr>
    <td class="loqhArea2Area">
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1Val1" class="InputItem" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:ListBox>
    </td>
    <td class="loqhArea3Area">
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2Val1" class="InputItem" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:ListBox>
    </td>
    <td class="loqhArea4Area">
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox3Val1" class="InputItem" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
    </td>
</tr>
```

These boxes are linked together in a sense, the choice in the first box is used to populate the second one and so fourth. In order to get the information from them I use this code snippet:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
// Do some other stuff ...

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Fill the boxes on initial load
    }
    else
    {
        // INeedTheData takes an ID-string (in this case "Val1")
        // and the selected indexes as ints
        INeedTheData("Val1",
                      ListBox1Val1.SelectedIndex,
                      ListBox2Val1.SelectedIndex,
                      ListBox3Val1.SelectedIndex);

    }
    // Some error handling    
}
```

The problem is that the SelectedIndexes all returns `-1`, which obviously is not what I need.

I have been googleing like crazy for a solution to this problem. All clues or leads are welcome. Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
Maybe this can be of any clue to anyone, my predecessor (who I have not been able to reach unfortunately) implemented this rather strange code that actually works. Or should I say sort of works. The thing is we wanted some kind of more reliable code so I set out to re-write it.

```
INeedTheData("Val1"
    , Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("ctl01$ListBox1Val1") ? Request.Form["ctl01$ListBox1Val1"] == string.Empty ? 0 : int.Parse(Request.Form["ctl01$ListBox1Val1"]) : 0
    , Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("ctl01$ListBox2Val1") ? Request.Form["ctl01$ListBox2Val1"] == string.Empty ? 0 : int.Parse(Request.Form["ctl01$ListBox2Val1"]) : 0
    , Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("ctl01$ListBox3Val1") ? Request.Form["ctl01$ListBox3Val1"] == string.Empty ? 0 : int.Parse(Request.Form["ctl01$ListBox3Val1"]) : 0);
```

This solution is not desirable since it gets the data using hardcoded html id's, which may be subject to change when rebuilding and reorganizing stuff on the page in the future. Anyhow I thought it should be entered here since it is the reason for me to rewrite it.

As stated above, all comments are welcome! Thanks!

**Update ii (answer to @Deeptechtons): Desired behaviour**
I have a group of three ListBoxes used to navigate and make choices from a tree graph. The first box (`ListBox1Val1`) is populated directly from a database. The second (`ListBox2Val1`) is empty until the user has selected his choice in the first. Doing so causes the children of the selected node in the first listbox to load into the second. Same thing goes for listbox number three (`ListBox3Val1`). Select a node in the second box and the third one is populated.

Comment: Why are you doing this in OnInit rather than PageLoad?

Comment: I don't know actually. I'm new to the project and also to asp.net development, to be fair. I'll try to move the code!

Comment: @Lazarus: It gives the same behaviour. :(

Comment: @Lazarus @dotmartin Could you both enable viewstate on those listbox and then rebuild the project and test. `<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1Val1" class="InputItem" runat="server"  EnableViewState="True" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:ListBox>`

Comment: @Deeptechtons: Sadly the problem remains.

Comment: @dotmartin Is this what you do, Listbox selected index chanded, postback selectedindex, with listbox2 selected index and listbox3 selected index. If yes then, listbox2 selected index = -1 if nothing is selected. as in example 1

Comment: @Deeptechtons: I have updated the question with a description of the desired behaviour, not entirely sure if this answers your question though! Please come back to me if it doesn't..

Comment: @dotmartin could you post the databind code, where you do Listboxval1.DataBind(). Are these inside the update panel with children as triggers set as true.

Comment: @Deeptechtons Yeah, thing is that this is such bad written code I cannot follow anything. I have tried every trick in my arsenal, I think it needs rewriting from the top down. I'm leaning towards giving up and posting a new ticket for a total re-design during our next sprint. 

Any comments on how you would solve this?

Comment: @dotmartin i will post a working code in few minutes with both aspx and cs file

Comment: @Deeptechtons Looking forward to it!

Comment: @dotmartin please look at the code and try to replicate it

Comment: I'm on it @Deeptechtons!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@dotmartin Here is the code you need on the Cs file

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ListBox1.DataSource = GetList();
            ListBox1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox2.DataSource = GetSecondList(ListBox1.SelectedIndex);
        ListBox2.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox3.Items.Add(new ListItem(ListBox1.SelectedValue + "-" + ListBox2.SelectedValue, "Wippie"));
    }

    private ListItemCollection GetList()
    {
        ListItemCollection lstNumbers = new ListItemCollection();
        lstNumbers.Add(new ListItem("1", "One"));
        lstNumbers.Add(new ListItem("2", "Two"));
        lstNumbers.Add(new ListItem("3", "Three"));
        lstNumbers.Add(new ListItem("4", "Four"));
        lstNumbers.Add(new ListItem("5", "Five"));
        return lstNumbers;
    }

    private ListItemCollection GetSecondList(int iSelectedIndex)
    {
        ListItemCollection lstRandom = new ListItemCollection();
        System.Random RandNum = new System.Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            lstRandom.Add(new ListItem(RandNum.Next(ListBox1.SelectedIndex, i + 1).ToString(), "random"));
        }
        return lstRandom;
    }
```

i had just generated some random numbers to be binded to the listbox.

**Below is the aspx file code,**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional" childrenastriggers="true">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div>
                        <asp:ListBox id="ListBox1" autopostback="true" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            width="200"></asp:ListBox></div>
                    <div>
                        <asp:ListBox id="ListBox2" autopostback="true" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            width="200"></asp:ListBox></div>
                    <div>
                        <asp:ListBox id="ListBox3" autopostback="true" runat="server" width="200"></asp:ListBox>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for your great efforts! The problem with the implementation we used earlier was that the code was simply not readable and structured enough. Your example clarifies a lot of things. Once again, thank you for helping me out! Much appreciated.

Comment: @dotmartin you are welcome! do Stack here your questions when you hit end of the road ;D

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in ASP.NET, control events happen after a page load in the page life-cycle: [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

I guess (but not sure about the exact name) the drop-down should have a `SelectedIndexChanged` event, where you should think of taking the new selection.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Interesting link, helped me to understand a lot of things I have been wondering about the page life cycle process.